# Uninstalled XAML Spy ages ago, but project still references it

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, silverlight

I used a program called XAML spy in my C# Silverlight development. I want on a cleanup spree a few months ago and removed it.

Today I opened an old project that still seems to reference it. Running the code produces a big red bar at the top of my silverlight control with:

```
Failed to connect to the XAML Spy Service (127.0.0.1:4530). An attempt was made to a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
(button)
Reconnect
```

How do I get my project to forget that it was ever connected to XAML spy?

What I've tried so far:

- Looking on the company's website - they tell me how to fix it by suggesting firewall fixes etc, but not how to get rid of it
- Checking in the .sln and .csproj files (no references i could see)

Edit: I found the below line in my xxxx.Silverlight.csproj file

```
<Import Project="$(XamlSpyInstallPath)MSBuild\FirstFloor.XamlSpy.Silverlight.targets" Condition="'$(XamlSpyInstallPath)' != '' and '$(Configuration)' == 'DEBUG'" />
```

- Checking in the build options of the solution, nothing i could see either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably when you set up the connection you went through this kind of process:
http://xamlspy.com/learn/tutorials/connect

That being the case, undo those changes. i.e. Either open `App.xaml.cs` and remove the service you defined there, or remove it from xaml `<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>` if you chose that method.

Comment: i have found a suspect line here in this file: xxx.silverlight.csproj
    <Import Project="$(XamlSpyInstallPath)MSBuild\FirstFloor.XamlSpy.Silverlight.targets" Condition="'$(XamlSpyInstallPath)' != '' and '$(Configuration)' == 'DEBUG'" />

Do you think that's the right ting to remove? Or is that auto generated?

Comment: In that case I would search the entire codebase for `XamlSpy` and `xaml spy`, if you can't find the hooks you added when setting it up.